# Django - write Python code in an elegant way

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a situation as shown below:

in models.py:

```
    class singer(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        nickName = models.CharField()
        numSongs= models.IntegerField()

   class writer(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        numBooks = models.IntegerField()


    class weeklyTimeSinger(models.Model):
        singerID = models.ForeignKey(singer, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'hook1')
        dayWeek = models.IntegerField() 
        startHour = models.TimeField()
        stopHour = models.TimeField()
    
    class weeklyTimeWriter(models.Model):
        writerID = models.ForeignKey(writer, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'hook2')
        dayWeek = models.IntegerField() 
        startHour = models.TimeField()
        stopHour = models.TimeField()
```

in view.py:

```
class Filters(APIView):
    def queryFilter(self, querySet, request, singerOtWriter):
            param1 = int(request.GET.get('param1', 0))
            param2 = int(request.GET.get('param2', 0))

        if singerOtWriter == "singer":
             querySet = querySet.filter(weeklyTimeSinger_dayWeek=param1)
             querySet = querySet.filter(weeklyTimeSinger_startHour__lt=param2) 
             querySet = querySet.update(.....
             ....a lot of operation on querySet
        else if singerOtWriter == "writer":
             querySet = querySet.filter(weeklyTimeWriter_dayWeek=param1)
             querySet = querySet.filter(weeklyTimeWriter_startHour__lt=param2) 
             querySet = querySet.update(.....
             ....a lot of operation on querySet, the same of the case singer

       return querySet 


class Artist(Filters):
    def get(self, request):
        querySetSinger = singer.objects.all().annotate(numWorks= F('numSongs'))
        querySetSinger = self.queryFilter(querySetSinger , request, "singer")
        querySetSinger = querySetSinger.values('name', 'numWorks')

        querySetWriter = writer.objects.all().annotate(numWorks= F('numBooks'))
        querySetWriter = self.queryFilter(querySetWriter , request, "writer")
        querySetWriter = querySetWriter.values('name', 'numWorks')

        values = querySetSinger.union(querySetWriter)
        serialized = ArtistSerializers(values, many = True)
        return Response(serialized.data)
```

In queryFilter function I have 2 different flows depending on singerOtWriter parameter. The 2 flows are long and identical execpt for "weeklyTimeWriter" or "weeklyTimeSinger" tables name and I don't want to repeat those lines of code because it looks dirty. I haven't reported all the lines of code but there are many.

Is there a better and more elegant way to rewrite this code and to generalize those operations?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

keep same table for singer/writer ans use type field. You can also filter easily.

models.py be like:-

```
artistTypes = (
        ('Singer', 'Singer'),
        ('Writer', 'Writer'),
    )

class artistName(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()
      nickName = models.CharField()
      artistType = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=artistTypes)
      numReleases = models.IntegerField()

class timeSpent(models.Model):
    artistID = models.ForeignKey(artistName, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    dayWeek = models.IntegerField() 
    startHour = models.TimeField()
    stopHour = models.TimeField()
```

Comment: Hi, I need to let models separated.

Comment: you asked for elegant way. But why you want to keep models separated?

Comment: I need that for other reasons. Do you know an other way?

Comment: you can create two field in model for singer and writer after that keep other field empty.